# Why my JSON data erasing after going from current viewcontroller to otherviewcontroller in swift

Tags: json, swift, viewcontroller

in my project.. in editprofileVC i am able parse JSON and i am able to show it in collectionview **but when i move from that `editprofileVC` to some other viewcontroller and coming to  `editprofileVC`.. then the JSON data is not showing**.. but all the data in backend.. but in my collectionview its not displaying.. why?

code for my JSON parsing

```
@IBAction func imgtitleSaveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    postServiceCall()
}

fileprivate func postServiceCall(){
    
   if titleTextfield.text?.trim() == ""{
   return self.view.makeToast("please add service title")
   }
    let parameters = ["image_title" : titleTextfield.text?.trim() ?? ""]
    
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.uploadMultipartFormData(param: parameters, url: CommonUrl.edit_profile_images, image: imageProfile, fileName: "image", vc: self, isHeaderNeeded: true) {(responseData) in
        print("edit profile result \(responseData)")
            if let result = responseData.dict?["result"] as? NSDictionary{
                    let success = result["status"] as? [String : Any]
                    let message = success?["message"] as? String

                if message == "Success"{
                    self.arrImageItems.append(ImageItemModel(title: self.titleTextfield.text, imgTitle: self.imageProfile))
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                else{
                    self.view.makeToast(CommonMessages.somethingWentWrong)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in the above code if i tap on `imgtitleSaveBtn` data is added to collectionview.. but if i moce from this viewcontroller to other viewcontroller then data is erasing.. why?... please do help

Comment: Are you sure that when you are moving from "other viewcontroller" you go back to original "editprofileVC" and not the new instance?

Comment: @MikhailVasilev yes.. pls do help

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I can not see exactly where the data is being added to the collection view.

I will suggest you create a global variable on editprofileVC class and hold the data in there, and reload collection view on viewDidAppear

Comment: this is collectionview data `self.arrImageItems.append(ImageItemModel(title: self.titleTextfield.text, imgTitle: self.imageProfile))`

Comment: whats the solution for erasing data while moving to anotherVC

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you called the method postServiceCall() at viewDidLoad again. Don't forget to empty the collection.

Add the following line of code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    arrImageItems.removeAll()
    postServiceCall()
}
```

The above method will be called every time the view appear on screen.